# return value by chaining through several class

Tags: c#, .net

My project uses code of the following structure and i am having difficult time understanding it.
So i tried to break this down to create a simple program but one which uses the same structure...

The place i have a problem is in the main class. It uses  `Console.WriteLine(result.One.Two.Three)`.
As `resut.One.Two.Three`, chains through 3 classes, I cannot understand what the contents of `class XYZ, class ABC, and classA` would be like.

I have created the classes with property, can someone please help fill out the  `class XYZ, class ABC, and classA` with a string variable/values and return value from Main class. I have been trying this all day, but couldn't get this to work. Any help in this would be highly helpful for me in understanding.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main()
    {
        XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
        Abc result = xyz.Display("Don");

        // This prints some actual value say : John
        Console.WriteLine(result.One.Two.Three);
    }
}

public class XYZ
{
    public Abc Display(string Name)
    {
        Abc result=new Abc();

        return result;
    }
}

public class Abc
{
    A a = new A();
    public A One
    {
        get
        {
            return a;
        }
        set { }
    }
}

public class A
{   
    B b = new B();
    public B Two
    {
        get        
        {
            return b;
        }
        set
        {
            b.Three = "BOSS";
        }
    }

}

public class B
{
    public string Three;
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Please rephrase it. All we can really tell is that there is badly written code here.

Comment: yepp.. understand that...i just pasted the code i was currently learning....
what i basically want to know is result.One.Two.Three moves through three classes and then prints value.. can i have a example of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    Console.WriteLine(a.One.Two.Three);
}

public class A
{
    public B One { get { return new B(); }}
}

public class B
{
    public C Two { get { return new C(); }}
}

public class C
{
    public string Three { get { return "Test"; }}
}
```

As bejger says, this is generally frowned on for breaking the Law of Demeter (code working with `A` objects really shouldn't have to care about `C` objects).

Comment: thanks mate.. exactly what i was looking for... thanks for ur effort

Answer (score 2):

The following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(result.One.Two.Three);
```

Is an example of breaking the Law of Demeter, which makes the code more error-prone and usually less readable.This principle says: "Only talk to your immediate friends." 
You should try to stick to this principle whenever it is possible (and in your case I think it would be possible).

You can read more about the Law of Demeter here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter

Comment: oh yeah.. i could'nt google this aswell as I did not know the term Law of Demeter... I now can google i think...thanks!!